# How to fix policy based authorization in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-identity

I'm trying to implement a policy based authorization on my Movies controller to only allow access for an Admin user.

I added an authorization policy "CanManageMovies" and assigned it to the Admin role. Then, I added the policy to my Movies controller. I seeded the Admin role and user in my Db.

```cs
// Authorization policy in Startup.cs ConfigureServices method

services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("CanManageMovies",
                    policy => policy.RequireRole("Admin"));
            });
```

```cs
// Movies controller

[Authorize(Policy = "CanManageMovies")]
    public class MoviesController : Controller
    {
      // code removed for brevity
    }
```

```cs
// This seeds the admin user and role. 
// The SeedData method is called in the Startup configure method. 

public class MyIdentityDbInitializer
    {
        public static void SeedData(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager,
            RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager)
        {
            SeedRoles(roleManager);
            SeedUsers(userManager);
        }

        public static void SeedUsers(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager)
        {
            if (userManager.FindByNameAsync
                ("user@vidly.com").Result == null)
            {
                IdentityUser user = new IdentityUser();
                user.UserName = "user@vidly.com";
                user.Email = "user1@localhost";

                IdentityResult result = userManager.CreateAsync
                (user, "Password#1").Result;

                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user,
                                        "User").Wait();
                }
            }

            if (userManager.FindByNameAsync
            ("admin@vidly.com").Result == null)
            {
                IdentityUser user = new IdentityUser();
                user.UserName = "admin@vidly.com";
                user.Email = "admin@vidly.com";

                IdentityResult result = userManager.CreateAsync
                (user, "Password#1").Result;

                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user,
                                        "Admin").Wait();
                }
            }
        }

        public static void SeedRoles(RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager)
        {
            if (!roleManager.RoleExistsAsync("User").Result)
            {
                IdentityRole role = new IdentityRole();
                role.Name = "User";
                IdentityResult roleResult = roleManager.
                CreateAsync(role).Result;
            }


            if (!roleManager.RoleExistsAsync
            ("Admin").Result)
            {
                IdentityRole role = new IdentityRole();
                role.Name = "Admin";
                IdentityResult roleResult = roleManager.
                CreateAsync(role).Result;
            }
        }
    }
```

When I run the app, navigate to Movies, and login with the Admin user, I expect to access the view, but I receive a "Not Authorized" message.

Comment: have you tried converting the method SeedUsers to async and awaiting the calls to usermanager or maybe using the synchronous AddToRole instead of AddToRoleAsync?

Comment: Did you add the line `app.UseAuthentication();` in Startup.Configure? Take a look at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?#order)

Comment: @MattLuccasPhaureJensen The SeedUser method is successful after checking the Db. Do you think converting the method to async is the root of the problem?

Comment: @RuardvanElburg `app.UseAuthentication();` is in my Startup.Configure.

Comment: My thought is that it is either the fact that the user isn’t added to the role correctly or it is that the policy isn’t set up correctly. But I think if you start awaiting your async calls or switch to synchronous calls that might fix it. Because with what you are doing it is easy for something completely unforeseeable to happen at run time.

Comment: Where is the code where you login? Are you adding the roles to the Identity on login?

Comment: @RuardvanElburg The users and roles are seeded in the Startup.cs Configure method file by calling

```c#
MyIdentityDbInitializer.SeedData(userManager, roleManager);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if  the ConfigureServices method and the Configure method in Startup.cs like below:

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
            .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
            .AddDefaultUI(UIFramework.Bootstrap4)
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("CanManageMovies",
                policy => policy.RequireRole("Admin"));
        });
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IServiceProvider serviceProvider, UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager, RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        MyIdentityDbInitializer.SeedData(userManager, roleManager);

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

[Here](https://microsoftapc-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/v-xuelc_microsoft_com/EXKHqgMy8t9Hl5ptgah0GTwB-2CI6IegasEQovyUCHXAjg?e=AY8gqZ) is a simple working demo , you could refer to and check the difference .

Comment: This is in my IdentityHostingStartup.cs Configure method: 

`services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>().AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
                    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<VidlyIdentityDbContext>();`

When I had this in my ConfigureServices method in Startup.cs, I was getting an error msg along the lines of 'Identity Schema already exists'.

Comment: @hagenderouen , Have you checked the code in the link I provided and what is different from yours? It would be better that you could share more details (such as Startup.cs , DbContext class ...) or share a demo that can reproduce the issue , currently , we can not reproduce the issue with the existing code.